# Blender 2D Platformer Realistic Jump

Tags: game-engine

The jump I want I find extremely hard to get to work. It is like every 2D platformer jump. However I can NOT use the "Character" physics type in the physics tab because I NEED rigid body for my character. So, I need a jump as follows:

Press W to jump, 
If you hold W you do the full entire jump (Lets say 2 units up?) 
If you let go at any time the jump will fall and cancel, and you should not be able to spam W and start jumping in mid-air as the Z LOC in simple motion does.
You can only jump when you are touching ground, aka collision sensor.

PLEASE I have been going crazy trying to use properties and timers to make sure nothing glitches and its just a normal freakin jump! :(

Comment: So you want to "charge" the jump? Means you start charging when pressing <w> and perform the jump when releasing <w>? The duration between press and release determines the charge?

Comment: No, when you press W you jump. If you hold it the entire time, it will perform the entire jump full length highest point till it falls. However if you let go lets say when you are halfway through the entire jump, it will then cancel the jump and you will fall. But like I said I dont want to be able to double jump in mid air or anything.

Comment: So it is like a rocket? The object get constant up-force while holding <w>. When you release it the up force stops letting the gravity push the object down. The next <w> will only be considered  while touching the ground?

Comment: Almost, except it wont be a rocket, its just like a jump... meaning it has a force going up and then it eventually falls. Like just a regular jump, nothing too weird, but its surprisingly hard to do this.

Comment: A regular jump gets an initial force and that's it. Typically you do not flap your hands to go higher and higher. What you described is that you want more forces after the jump already started.